# Can you call a UserControl Server Function from the same UserControls Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, user-controls

I am not certain if this question has been posted already and I've checked the suggested SO links but none seem to pertain precisely to the question. So if anyone believes this is a potential duplicate, please post the link of the proposed answer and forgive this post.

There may be more than one way to approach my problem but for brevity, I have a User Control for which I'd like to use JavaScript or JQuery calls to its corresponding Server Side methods.

For example, say I were to have some Server-Side code for my User Control such as:

```
 public partial class UserControls_MyControl : UserControl
 {
      public string ExecuteThis(string someValue)
      {
          return someValue;
      }
 }
```

I would like to call the ExecuteThis method from the User Controls Client Side using JavaScript. I know that this is possible if it were a call from the Parent Page using among other mechanisms; PageMethods. But how can this be achieved when the Client and Server code both reside within the User Control.

I ran across some posts and reference articles suggesting the use of a WebService Proxy and I've tried that with some success as far as calling the WebService from the User Controls Client Script using AJAX.

```
function MakeWebServiceCall()
{
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         url: "/WebServices/MyService.asmx/SomeMethod",
         data: "{}",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (msg) {
             alert(msg.d);
         },
         error: function(error)
         {
             alert(error.responseText);
         }
     });
}
```

But how can I tie the WebService call back to the User Controls Method? Or is it even possible? Or is there some more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to have a method in the page that is using the user control marked as a WebMethod and that method would then call your user control method.

In your page:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string ExecuteThis(string somevalue)
{
   return userCtrl.ExecuteThis(somevalue);
}
```

In your ajax call:

```
url: "/MyPage.aspx/ExecuteThis"
```

Comment: Thanks pln, that was the answer! It took me a minute to figure out what you were proposing as a solution but I got it now. Although I "think" the Web Method would have to be marked as "Static" for it to work?

Comment: Actually I don't belive it will work since WebMethods cannot access the page at all since they are static. You can however move the logic to the page instead or create a web service or web api but I assume you wanted to actually manipulate the user control somehow from client script ?